# Some given parameters are not resolved when deploying a stack "not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to create and deploy a template that itself deploys a product from the AWS service catalog. Here is my template:

```yaml
Parameters:
  ProductId:
    Type: String
  ProvisioningArtifactName:
    Type: String
  Description:
    Type: String
  Region:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  VpcSize:
    Type: String
  BastionHostKeyName:
    Type: String
  ProvisioningArtifactName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  VPCAndMore:
    Type: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct
    Properties:
      ProductId: ProductId
      ProvisioningArtifactName: ProvisioningArtifactName
      ProvisioningParameters:
        - Key: Description
          Value: Description
        - Key: AvailabilityZones
          Value: Region
        - Key: VpcSize
          Value: VpcSize
        - Key: BastionHostKeyName
          Value: BastionHostKeyName
```

When I try to deploy it manually I enter all parameter values. They are definitely correct and from the correct type. But once I deploy it I get an error like this:

```
Product ProductId not found. (Service: ServiceCatalog, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 35f27a2a-1317-48d0-815e-16ebe949d039, Extended Request ID: null)
```

For some reason the `ProductId` parameter is not resolved it seems like.

**What am I missing? Or is CF not supporting parameter resolving outside of `ProvisioningParameters`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For [Intrinsic function Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) need to reference the values defined like below:

```yaml
Parameters:
  ProductId:
    Type: String
  ProvisioningArtifactName:
    Type: String
  Description:
    Type: String
  Region:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
  VpcSize:
    Type: String
  BastionHostKeyName:
    Type: String
  ProvisioningArtifactName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  VPCAndMore:
    Type: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct
    Properties:
      ProductId: !Ref ProductId
      ProvisioningArtifactName: !Ref ProvisioningArtifactName
      ProvisioningParameters:
        - Key: Description
          Value: !Ref Description
        - Key: AvailabilityZones
          Value: !Ref Region
        - Key: VpcSize
          Value: !Ref VpcSize
        - Key: BastionHostKeyName
          Value: !Ref BastionHostKeyName
```

Comment: Wow how did I miss that. I was most of the time looking at a JSON template example in the Terraform docs and never noticed the `ref`. thanks for the fast answer

Comment: @trallnag glad it worked out. If this helps can you mark this as solved. This helps the community and anyone who StumbleUpon this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're only inserting the parameters name without referencing it.

You need to use the intrinsic function **[!Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html)**. Like this:

```yaml
Parameters:
    ProductId:
    Type: String
    ProvisioningArtifactName:
    Type: String
    Description:
    Type: String
    Region:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    VpcSize:
    Type: String
    BastionHostKeyName:
    Type: String
    ProvisioningArtifactName:
    Type: String
Resources:
    VPCAndMore:
    Type: AWS::ServiceCatalog::CloudFormationProvisionedProduct
    Properties:
        ProductId: !Ref ProductId
        ProvisioningArtifactName: !Ref ProvisioningArtifactName
        ProvisioningParameters:
        - Key: Description
            Value: !Ref Description
        - Key: AvailabilityZones
            Value: !Ref Region
        - Key: VpcSize
            Value: !Ref  VpcSize
        - Key: BastionHostKeyName
            Value: !Ref BastionHostKeyName
```